# How do Jade blocks work - Jade

Tags: pug

I am trying to use a `Jade` block and my content is not displaying.  Here is my `index.jade`:

```
//index.jade
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
  section.content
    div(ng-view)
```

It is adding the `layout` file like I expect.  Here is that file:

```
//layout.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon",type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/site.css")
  body(ng-app="app")
    h1 Hello Worldd
    include scripts
```

But it does not include my `main.jade`:

```
// main.jade
h1 This is a Partial
h2 {{ myVar }}
```

or any of the code after it.  This is my first time using `Jade` so I am struggling.  Also, what is the `-content` for when you are including a `block`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A block is a "block" of content you want to insert to the template you are extending it from.

Assuming directory layout:

```
|--views  
   |--layout.jade  
   |--index.jade  
   |--main.jade
```

Here is an example using your templates:

//layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon",type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/site.css")
  body(ng-app="app")
    h1 Hello Worldd
    block content
    include scripts
```

Then all other pages that extend from layout.jade can insert content into that block:

//index.jade

```
extends layout
block main-content
  section.content
    div(ng-view)
```

//main.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  h1 This is a Partial
  h2 {{ myVar }} // which should be: h2= myVar
```

This will render (assuming using Express):

//index.html

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon",type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/site.css")
  body(ng-app="app")
    h1 Hello Worldd
    section.content
      div(ng-view)
    include scripts
```

//main.html

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon",type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/site.css")
  body(ng-app="app")
    h1 Hello Worldd
    h1 This is a Partial
    h2 {{ myVar }} // which should be: h2= myVar
    include scripts
```